# larger bitmap how to fit into android device screen

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I have confusion for the loading of the bitmap into android device screen or any digital device for example LED TV screen here my android mobile screen resolution like 768x1280 pixels and I want to load bitmap resolution like 3000x2000 pixels here may be two type of possibility arise first one directly load bitmap without and resizing of the original bitmap second one form original bitmap to take the resizable bitmap and load into device screen but question arise into the first case how to load larger bitmap into small device screen can anybody help me for this confusion.

For reference consider this image : 
Here this image have resolution 3000x2000 pixels and mobile screen resolution 768x1280 pixels.

[image]

Comment: Check out this link for the possibilities http://abhiandroid.com/ui/scaletype-imageview-example.html

Comment: There is no difference for big or small. And it is unclear what you mean by screen. But for displaying a bitmap in an image view you use imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap). (Or like that). Choose the right scale type first.

Answer (score 1):

Use "picasso" plugin:
[picasso page](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Example:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("link or @drawable/...").into(imageView);
```

You can add .fit() and image will fill imageView.

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load("link or @drawable/...")
.fit()
.into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rotate image to 90 degree(either outside or inside XML), Then Fit with scaleType attribute.

1. Firstly either you can add rotated image to your resource or rotate it with XML attribute, like this.

   ```
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/image"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:rotation="90"
       android:src="@mipmap/your_image" />
   ```
2. Then, Scale it with scaleType attributes (fitCenter, centerInside or centerCrop)

   ```
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/image"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:rotation="90"
       android:scaleType="fitCenter"
       android:src="@mipmap/your_image" />
   ```

**Note**: If you only give scaleType to your ImageView without rotation then your image will be stretched.